# Joomla blog override- How can I access articles in a subcategory?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating a Joomla blog override for an eCommerce site and am looking for some help. I'd like to use the subcategories as a sort of secondary nav or filter on the page to determine which articles are displayed. They should all display on the same page, just one category (user selected) at a time.

I can see that the 
    $this->children[$this->category->id]
calls the subcategories, I just need help figuring out how to access the subcategory's articles once it has been selected.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this something you want to do without reloading the page?  Also, is the sub-category filter list going to be display inline the component's view or in a dedicated module?

Comment: If possible I think I'd like to do it with out reloading the page but really I just care that they're all on the same page. Right now the subcategories are in the component's view. I'm hoping to incorporate both elements in my modified blog.php.

Comment: Have you tried implementing any javascript to hide/show based on category ids?  You can use the template override for the core view to insert the ids into the containing row divs.

Comment: There is now a http://joomla.stackexchange.com you might want to try moving it there

Answer (score 0):

Just a few basic directions here:

As Brian Boli said in his comment, javascript will be needed for this. The way you will have to implement it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If these are only a few articles, then you can do it the way Brian said, by calling/load all articles in the page and use simple javascript (jQuery probably) to show/hide article-elements in the page based on their id.

But if your category/ies contain hundreds of articles, this might not be that efficient.
Using the subcategories as a filter and have all these articles appearing in the same blog page/url without reloading with navigation and such, will require AJAX implementation. So the subcat filter will call the relatives articles from the database and update the view instantly.

If you are not up for all this, you may leave the idea of instant view update on the same page, and create a simple module (or maybe search for an existing one) that will work dynamically on the blog page (but not necessarily), and will display all subcategories with links to their blog layout.

#### Update:

To get the articles of each category:

hmm... well you have the category id, so you could either directly call the articles from the database, or better use the Joomla Model to get the articles of each category, within the blog_children.php template.

```
$model = JModelList::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));

$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $child->id);
$items = $model->getItems();


foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "<div class='span12'>";
    echo $item->title;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Hope this will take you closer to what you want achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone! I think my main issue right now (and it's probably a simple one) is figuring out the correct way to call the articles of the subcategories. I realize that the     <?php foreach ($this->children[$this->category->id] as $id => $child) : ?>    loops through each of the current category's subcategories, but I don't know the proper way to call the articles in those subcategories...

Comment: updated the answer on how to get the articles for each category.